# Sorting an array in openmp

Tags: openmp, insertion-sort

I have an array of 100 elements that needs to be sorted with insertion sort using OpenMP. When I parallelize my sort it does not give correct values. Can some one help me

```
void insertionSort(int a[])
{
    int i, j, k;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
            k = a[i];
            for (j = i; j > 0 && a[j-1] > k; j--)
                    #pragma omp critical
                    a[j] = a[j-1];
                    a[j] = k;
    }
}
```

Comment: An incorrect answer is accepted in this question, while a similar question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905410/insertion-sort-in-openmp has a correct answer. I suggest to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables "j" and "k" need to be private on the parallel region.  Otherwise you have a data race condition.

Comment: @ejd I get the following output when I make 'j' and 'k' private

Comment: (2), (2), (3), (4), (4), (4), (5), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (10), (11), (15), (29), (34), (45), (54), (63), (66), (77), (99), (1100), (1254), (1300), (4322), (5), (5), (6), (6), (7), (7), (8), (8), (9), (19), (22), (24), (27), (32), (33), (34), (34), (39), (42), (43), (44), (45), (45), (48), (54), (54), (54), (54), (54), (55), (58), (64), (65), (66), (76), (79), (89), (92), (95), (98), (100), (344), (667), (2999), (5454), (5454), (9377), (8), (6), (6), (23), (25), (25), (32), (33), (43), (43), (43), (45), (45), (52), (54), (63), (64), (75), (435), (665), (776), (954), (2323), (9444),

Comment: I was just commenting on data scoping. You need to look at the critical region.

Comment: @ejd I made it critical so that only one thread can enter while the value is being manipulated. What can I do different.

Comment: You are not protecting the entire value swap.

Comment: @ejd hmmm so what can I do. I don't think moving the critical section above the second for loop can work

Answer (score 3):

Unless it's a homework, sorting as few as 100 elements in parallel makes no sense: the overhead introduced by parallelism will far outweigh any performance benefit.

And, insertion sort algorithm is inherently serial. When a[i] is processed, it is supposed that all previous elemens in the array are already sorted. But if two elements are processed in parallel, there is obviously no such guarantee.

A more detailed explanation of why insertion sort cannot be parallelized in the suggested way [is given by @dreamcrash in his answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905410/insertion-sort-in-openmp/13909410#13909410).

Comment: yea it is homework, bit of a last minute decision to do this in openmp. I do realize for an array this size insertion works much fast sequentially. The timings I get are 0.00016 secs versus 0.00216 in openmp.

Comment: +1, To bad the right answer was not selected. I had answer a similar question moments ago, where the OP use this same algorithm with this same parallelization, maybe the OP took from here, thinking it as correct.