# Insertion sort with openmp

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I searched on the internet but couldn't find much about.

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void insertionsort(int vector[], int tam){
    int i, j, tmp;
    for(i = 1; i < tam; i++){
        j = i;
        while(j > 0 && vector[j-1] > vector[j]){
            tmp = vector[j];
            vector[j] = vector[j-1];
            vector[j-1] = tmp;
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

how parallelize the insertion sort with openmp?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to parallelize this algorithm.

Note that an invariant of the first loop is that the `vector` is already sorted from `[0..i-1]`. You cannot run the first loop in parallel, basically because each iteration depends on the previous one except the first one.

About the nested while loop: the algorithm shifts to the right the elements whose values are greater than `vector[i]`. I'm not sure how to parallelize it or if it's worthy, but I have a strong feeling that I'd be complicated: you will need to change your code and use more memory to avoid data-races. About the data-races: note that if we run all the iterations from `j=[1..i]` in parallel, a certain element may be read and written at the same time, so we need to take care of that. Apart from that, this implementation will probably suffer unbalanced load.

Related question:
[Insertion Sort in OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905410/insertion-sort-in-openmp)